# OpenShift - which type of application choose for only front-end web?

Tags: cloud, hosting, web-hosting, frontend, openshift

I have only front-end files like -  `.html` , `.js` and `.css`  .

I want to host them in [OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/) such that they will be in [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) mode .

Which type of application under `OpenShift applications` should I have to choose in order to browse to these `.html` via the `OpenShift` domain ?

The are many options like - `JBoss Application Server 7` , `PHP 5.3` , `Python 2.6` , `Ruby 1.9` etc ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the php-5.3 or php-5.4 cartridge.  They will both work just fine with .html, .js, and .css files, you don't have to use PHP with them.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few starter projects available that each include support for serving HTML and static files.

Take your pick:

- PHP - [Silex-base](https://github.com/ryanj/silex-base)
- Nodejs - [Restify-base](https://github.com/ryanj/restify-base)
- Python - [Flask-base](https://github.com/ryanj/flask-base)
- Ruby - [Sinatra-base](https://github.com/ryanj/sinatra-base)

PHP will work great.  I usually use Nodejs so that I can take advantage of npm libraries, and so I can use javascript-based build tasks to help optimize my client-side code (browserify, grunt, etc).

Good luck!